# Using Query Language in AppsScript for a shared but NOT public spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is shared with me but **is not public available**.
When I use the following URL in any browser a csv is exported that contains all rows of the sheet for which column A matches with "productABC":

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheet id>/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid=<sheet id>&tq=select%20*%20where%20A%20contains%20'productABC'
```

So this works perfectly as expected.

Now I want to get the csv-file programmatically with an AppsScript code:

```
function getData() {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<spreadsheet id>/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&gid= 
<sheet id>&tq=select%20*%20where%20A%20contains%20'productABC'"
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

When I run the code I am assuming that it checks if the user (in this case me) has access to the spreadsheet (like when I open the spreadsheet with the URL in a browser). But I dont get any data. The result is just HTML-code of a Google log-in page.

When I make the spreadsheet available to public the code works fine.

Why is the code not considering that the spreadsheet is shared with me?

Thank you!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and Web Apps. Can I ask you about the details of your question?

Comment: My plan is to use the data from the spreadsheet and display some of the values in a WebApp with HTML-UI. This code is not existing so far because I already cant get the data in Apps Script.
Thanks for your hint. This is not a problem with the WebApp but already an issue with the AppsScript code. I will update my question.

Comment: Thank you for replying, About `I will update my question.`, I would like to wait for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `I have a spreadsheet that is shared with me but is not public available.`, in your script, I thought that the access token might be required to be used. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `But I dont get any data. The result is just HTML-code of a Google log-in page.`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

#### To:

```
var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } });
```

#### Note:

- If an error related to the scopes occurs, please add the following comment line to your script. By this, the script editor can automatically detect the required scope.

  ```
    // DriveApp.getFiles();
  ```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)